# How to replace multiple file name in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dir

(ANSWERED) I want to change file name from this directory. Let call them ai01.aif, ab01.aif to changedai01.aif, changedab01.aif.

```
import os, sys

path="/Users/Stephane/Desktop/AudioFiles"
dirs=os.listdir(os.path.expanduser(path))
i="changed"

for file in dirs:
    newname=i+file
    os.rename(file,newname)
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ai01.aif' -> 'changedai01.aif'
>>>
```

Comment: os.rename(path+file,path+newname)?

Comment: Nop= Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/Stephane/Desktop/AudioFilesai01.aif' -> '/Users/Stephane/Desktop/AudioFileschangedai01.aif'

Comment: you are not inside the directory and ofc can't rename file using just its name, you need absolute path to the file and its name

Comment: ok I ll try with path+"/"+file

Comment: Yep it is working @pianista! Tks.

Comment: `os.path.join(path, file)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no file named `ai01.aif` in the current directory (this is often the one your script is in, but might be elsewhere). The directory you got the content of is not the current directory. You will need to add the directory you're working in to the beginning of the filenames.

```
import os, sys

path = os.path.expanduser("/Users/Stephane/Desktop/AudioFiles")
dirs = os.listdir(path)
i    = "changed"

for file in dirs:
    newname = i + file
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, newname))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch to the path before you rename or use full names, so either add

```
os.chdir(path)
```

somewhere before the loop, or use

```
os.rename(os.path.join(path, newname), os.path.join(path, file))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an absolute path to your file, use join here:

```
file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
```

Answer (score 1):

My error=>

I am not inside the directory. So instead of

```
import os, sys

path="/Users/Stephane/Desktop/AudioFiles"
dirs=os.listdir(os.path.expanduser(path))
i="changed"

for file in dirs:
    newname=i+file
    os.rename(file,newname)
```

It should be:

```
import os, sys

path="/Users/Stephane/Desktop/AudioFiles"
dirs=os.listdir(os.path.expanduser(path))
i="changed"

for file in dirs:
    newname=i+file
```

## my error is down there

```
    os.rename(path+"/"+file, path+"/"+newname)
```

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use `os.path.join(path, file)` instead of `path + '/' + file`